# Swift 2/iOS 9 UITableViewCellStyle.Default constant not working

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm attempting to initialize a UITableViewCell, but it's not letting me refer to the style enum by name:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
```

Results in "Static member 'Default' cannot be used on instance of type 'UITableViewCellStyle."

If I just refer to the style as ".Default" and leave off the "UITableViewCellStyle" enum name from the beginning, it works fine. This is contrary to just about all the documentation and tutorials I've looked at online.

Any ideas why the first method is not working?

Comment: Hmm... looks like the error state was stuck in xcode or something. Not sure what would have caused it to begin with though.

Comment: I tested, both cases work fine. Did you try restart xcode or update xcode to latest version.

Comment: I have this same issue involving an iOS course at Udemy. Same problem exactly. Am searching for solutions now. Am using Swift 2.1, which does not allow for the .Default option.